# How to make a circuit of 6 lights connected to a single battery, with each light having its own switch

Tags: switches, homework, closed-loop

I have a school assignment on how to make a circuit with 6 lights connected to a single battery, with each light having its own switch. I'm wondering how to do this, and I'm hoping for guidance.

Comment: Please show a circuit of a battery a single lamp and, a single switch.

Comment: how do you connect 6 table lamps?

Comment: Can you provide a link to whatever course material you are following? What concepts have you learned so far?

Answer (score 2):

As this is a school assignment, I'm not going to give you the answer (otherwise, you wouldn't learn much), but I'm going to give you a few hints.

Hint 1 : start to try to solve the exercise for only 2 lights : once you have the solution for 2 lights, it should be rather easy to extrapolate to 6 lights instead. All following hints will be based on 2 lights only

Hint 2 : What ways do you have to connect 2 lights (without any switch) to a single battery?

Hint 3 : once you have found the different ways of connecting 2 lights(cf hint 2), try to add 2 switches, and see if you can command each light individually

Comment: First you must understand the function of an electrical switch. What does it do when turned on and what doesn't it do when it is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the "Schematic" icon to access the Circuit Lab app. You already know you need a battery, some switches, and some lamps. So here are these components. You can provide the wiring on your own, in your question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgp1Yt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>